# Mod Rewrite Dots Inside URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to RegEx and need a bit of help. While working on redirects in my htaccess I found in Google webmaster tools loads of URL's with .. in the middle, for example:

```
http://www.website.com/category/name-of-category../page/94/
```

My question is what cond and rule should I add to redirect each URL to the same one WITHOUT the dots. I forgot to mention that sometimes it appears with two dots and sometimes three.

I did a lot of searching on Stack Overflow for a solution but found no answer.

Comment: Can you post some examples from Google webmaster tools?  2 dots could possibly have been intended to go up a directory (needless with a URL, however) but 3 dots is really suspicious, like possibly not intended to be a real URL.

Comment: OK, so to make it clear, I only found two dots in Google which I found it pretty strange to begin with - so I decided to add a third dot to the URL and the browser brought up a 404 page...

Comment: Is the example you have above one of the _actual_ URLs. or does it look like `/category/name-of-category/../page/94/` (note the `/` before the `..`)?  `../` and `./` in a filesystem have special meanings, referring to one directory higher, and the current directory respectively.

Comment: This is the exact URL (names changed of course) built on WordPress.

Comment: If that is a real WordPress url it suggests there is a category actually named with the dots, no?

Comment: Well, I wish it were that simple... In my opinion this is a glitch in WP. In the end, what I'm looking for is a rewrite rule that will remove all two (or more) dots from my URLs. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you be very specific about the URLs:  What URL do end users originally click in their browsers?  What URL does that translate into internally to be executed by your web server and application?  What URL does the user ultimately see in the browser when all redirection is done?  Edit your question above to list all those examples, since mod_rewrite has to account for all of them separately (it isn't just a one-line mapping change)

Comment: I have the same problem.. wrong urls from outside pointing to my web e.g. /app/windows/parameter1/...  with three dosts goes to forbidden page. I can't fix it in htaccess. Two dots working with redirect, but three not.